# Websharing and Remote Login not working over local network

Tags: sharing

Someone gave me their old mac mini which is running OSX 10.6.  I decided to use it a home.

I went to network preferences, then clicked on Sharing.

I checked Web Sharing and Remote Login.

Under Web Sharing, it says the mac mini personal website is available at the address

`http://192.168.0.110/~johncomputer/`

So I opened up Safari on the mac mini and typed in that address, and I see a simple webpage that I created just minutes ago.  So that's fine.

I then went to my android phone which is on the same network.  I opened up chrome browser and typed in the `http://192.168.0.110/~johncomputer/` and the web page showed up which is great.

So then I turned off the monitor connected to my mac mini, WITHOUT turning off the mac mini (so i left the mac mini as is).   Then i went back to my android phone and pressed refresh on the chrome browser.  Now Chrome browser says it could not connect to `192.168.0.110`.

I turned on the mac mini monitor again and took a look at the Sharing settings, and it shows everything up and running.  In the Mac Mini safari, i typed in the `http://192.168.0.110/~johncomputer/` and the web page still showed up.  I edited the web page, then refreshed the browser again, and i see the changes.  So clearly the webserver is up and running.

But my android phone sitll can't connect to 192.168.0.110.  I went to other cmputers in my house, and none of them can connect to `192.168.0.110`.

All my devices/computers are able to connect with each other and with the internet.  They just can't seem to see the webpage at `192.168.0.110`.

I also can't seem to use ssh to login to `192.168.0.110`, even though the mac mini says it's on.

How do i correct this problem?

Answer (score 1):

OK i figured out the problem.  It seems my mac mini is losing internet connection/network every so often.  I don't know why it is, so going to post a separate question about this.